# absolutely positioned submenu with top property not working

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

Im have a problem with submenu which has `position:absolute;` and `top:5em;`. The submenu is hidden until you hover over parent (li element). Everything is working but when you hover over parent (li element) the submenu (li > ul element) is shown but you cant mouse-over (access) it because it's disappearing when mouse leaves parent (li element) area.

I found out that the `top: 5em;` is doing a *"break"* between LI and UL. When i try to reduce the `top: 5em;` to for instance `top: 1em;` (size where UL is just on border of parent (li element) or for instance goes a bit into parent (li element), then the menu is working!!

But i need it to have the top of my choice and still working.

How to achieve this with `position:absolute` and `top` properties?

Live demo: http://codepen.io/riogrande/pen/bEGzXm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find it strange you found the exact root cause of the problem, but has yet to figure out the fix.

Anyway the fix is to add a transparent child to the `<li>`, so that it fill the gap between the `<li>` and its `<ul>` child. In this case I use `li:before`:

```
&:before{
    content: '';
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 5em;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  &:hover:before{
    display:block;
  }
```

Demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mVdgdo

**Edited**: Answer edited to cover issue with insights from the OP himself.

Comment: Thanks mate! Very elegant solution!

Comment: Actually, this is just a half of an answer. If you :before to be displayed as block, then if you hover anywhere under li element in size of 5em height, the dropdown will be displayed. My solution is to display :before as none, and then display it as a block when you hover over li element

Comment: Ooh, you're absolutely correct friend. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help with everything!

Answer (score 0):

Solution based on Av Avt's answer

Anyway the fix is to add a transparent child to the `<li>`, so that it fill the gap between the `<li>` and its `<ul>` child. In this case I use `li:before`:

```
&:before {
        content: '';
        display: none;
        width: 100%;
        height: 5em;
        position: absolute;
        top: 100%;
        left:0;
}
```

And then when you hover over parent `<li>` display it as block so it fills the gap ONLY when parent `<li>` is hovered (active)

```
&:hover {
        &:before {
          display:block;
        }
        > ul {
          display: block;
        }
      }
```

Anyway thanks to @av-avt !! Without you i would not figure it out!